# How to use image string i got from .getExtra

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-intent

I have created a listview and i have parsed json data there (image and a few texts). Now i need to pass the image to the other activity on click, and i do it like i pass those texts by putExtra, and i can easy parse the texts there. But how do i parse the image in the new activity by .getExtra ( get the string but cannot parse it into imageview. 
My code below:
First activity:

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Testic.class);
            String prenos = list.get(position).getEmail();
            String voda = list.get(position).getPhone();
            String name = list.get(position).getName();
            String slika = list.get(position).getImage();
            intent.putExtra("mail", prenos);
            intent.putExtra("voda", voda);
            intent.putExtra("name", name);
            intent.putExtra("slika", slika);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Second activity:

```
        TextView probno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.probno);


    probno.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("mail"));

    TextView voda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voda);

    voda.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("voda"));

    TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

    name.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));

    ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika);
```

As you can see i haven't put any binder for the imageview cuz everything  i put didn't work. Rest works fine.

Comment: for this you have to do the task in adapter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create method (just copy paste):

```
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

And then call it on onCreate like this:

```
 new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika))
            .execute(getIntent().getExtras().getString("slika"));
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**For This you must use image loader library to load your images in imageview like**

[Universal ImageLoader.](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

[Facebook fresco.](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)
etc..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the String you sent. This is a possibility:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("slika"));
ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika);
slika.setImageURI(uri);
```

"slika" must be an id in your layout xml.

Comment: So basically i have url to an image from json. I parse it into the listview trough adapter. But when i click on an item in the listview, i want to pass that image to the other activity (for example, you click an item in google store and it opens up a generated details page that has that image from the listview in it). So basically i want that same image passed on to the other activity, and to be able to show it there.

Comment: So send the url from the json. Though it might be wise to download the image to a local cache and pass it's absolute path as the String

Comment: I do, but when i try to get it as image resource it searches for an int value. Basically when i try to use:
ImageView slika = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slika);


        slika.setImageResource //on this here i cannot get the value due to not being Int

Answer (score 0):

Put the path of the image in putExtra. Don't try to send image inform of Bitmap or imageview it will be heavy.

you can do like this.
Save filepath

```
intent.putExtra("imagePath", filepath);
```

to send the image through intent and use

```
String image_path = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
myimageview.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```